# What's the difference between `use` and `@before_compile`?

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

What's the difference between `use` and `@before_compile`? Both can be used to inject some code in to current module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One main difference is that the code in `__using__` is called and return value injected as soon as you call `use` within a module, while `__before_compile__` is called and the return value injected after all the code directly inside the module is executed, just before the module is compiled.

A simple program to demonstrate the difference:

```
defmodule When do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    IO.inspect :using
    __CALLER__.module |> Module.definitions_in |> IO.inspect
    quote do end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
    IO.inspect :before_compile
    __CALLER__.module |> Module.definitions_in |> IO.inspect
    quote do end
  end
end

defmodule Main do
  @before_compile When
  use When
  IO.puts "added `@before_compile` and `use`"
  def add(x, y), do: x + y
end
```

Output:

```
:using
[]
added `@before_compile` and `use`
:before_compile
[add: 2]
```

ExUnit [uses `@before_compile`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/6da34e02256f6ecbdafd1a574575d3d9b744bf24/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L284-L296) to define a function that returns all the tests to make it possible for the ExUnit runner to get and run all the tests.